# Constructor set/Get. How do I not set a value of less than 0 to return?

Tags: java

Provide a set and a get method for each instance variable. If the monthly salary is not positive, do not set its value.

The problem I'm having is "Not setting the value" 
Here is my code:

*Main.class*

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Employee myEmp  = new Employee("William", "Russell", 30000);
Employee myEmp2  = new Employee("Yevgeniya", "Pakhom", -1);
myEmp.displayMessage();
myEmp2.displayMessage();
}
}

Employee.class


public class Employee {

    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private double ySalary;

public Employee (String firstName, String lastName, double yearSalary)
    {
        fName = firstName;
        lName = lastName;
        ySalary = yearSalary;
    }
// Set First Name
    public void setFName (String firstName)
        {
        fName = firstName;
        }
// Get First Name
    public String getFName()
        {
        return fName;
        } 

   // Set Last Name
    public void setLName (String lastName)
        {
        lName = lastName;
        }
  //  Get Last Name
    public  String getLName()
        {
        return lName;
        } 

 // Set Salary
    public void setSalary (double yearSalary)
        {

            ySalary = yearSalary;

        }
// Get Salary
    public double getYearSalary()
        {

        return ySalary;

        }
// Display method
        public void displayMessage()
        {
            if (ySalary < 0)
                 System.out.printf("Hello %s %s, \nI see you're       currently making: %.2f\n", getFName(), getLName(),getYearSalary() );


 }
}
```

I have put a if statement in my displayMessage() method. But that is not "Setting it to nothing" I guess.

My wife had a similar problem and she set it under her "Get" but mine is not working the same way.

Comment: The [tag:homework] tag is obsolete and should not be used. Removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code to use Double.  Hope this helps you in setting null value.

```
public class JavaMainTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Employee myEmp  = new Employee("William", "Russell", 30000d);
Employee myEmp2  = new Employee("Yevgeniya", "Pakhom", null);
Employee myEmp3  = new Employee("Sernea", "Monsen", -1d);
myEmp.displayMessage();
myEmp2.displayMessage();
myEmp3.displayMessage();
}
}



 class Employee {

    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private Double ySalary;

public Employee (String firstName, String lastName, Double yearSalary)
    {
        fName = firstName;
        lName = lastName;
        if (yearSalary!=null)
        ySalary = yearSalary;
    }
// Set First Name
    public void setFName (String firstName)
        {
        fName = firstName;
        }
// Get First Name
    public String getFName()
        {
        return fName;
        } 

   // Set Last Name
    public void setLName (String lastName)
        {
        lName = lastName;
        }
  //  Get Last Name
    public  String getLName()
        {
        return lName;
        } 

 // Set Salary
    public void setSalary (Double yearSalary)
        {

            ySalary = yearSalary;

        }
// Get Salary
    public Double getYearSalary()
        {

        return ySalary;

        }
// Display method
        public void displayMessage()
        {
            if (ySalary == null)
                 System.out.printf("Hello %s %s, \nI see you're       currently making: %.6f\n", getFName(), getLName(),getYearSalary() );
            else if (ySalary < 0)
                 System.out.printf("Hello %s %s, \nI see you're       currently making: %.2f\n", getFName(), getLName(),getYearSalary() );


 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! this has helped a ton! I will study it and try to learn as much as possible. The d at the end of numbers is indicating its a double I take it?

Answer (score 1):

change setSalary as

```
public void setSalary (double yearSalary)
        {
            if (yearSalary <= 0) {
                 throw new IllegalArgumentException("yearSalary: " + yearSalary);
            }
            ySalary = yearSalary;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still on chapter 4, I think we get to exceptions soon!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you set that in your `setSalary()` method. That's your `setter` for `salary`.

In your case, inside the `Constructor` would be good enough.

```
public Employee (String firstName, String lastName, double yearSalary)
{
        fName = firstName;
        lName = lastName;
        if(yearSalary >= 0){
            ySalary = yearSalary;
        }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! this one is very easy. It shows up as 0.00 instead of null

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this function inside the constructor instead. Or just put an `if` inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the preconditions inside the setSalary method and may optionally throw  exceptions (like IllegalArgumentException).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee{

   //Use factory method instead to check for pre conditions
   public static Employee newEmployee(String firstName, String lastName, double salary){
       if(salary < 0){
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Salary cannot be negetive");
       }

      return new Employee(firstName, lastName, salary);
   }

}
```

If you also have a setter method then the condition for negative should also be checked there to throw Illegal argument exception.

**Why using factory method:** As doing work in constructor is not a good practice, doing the pre condition check in factory method or an actual factory is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

in setSalary() you can check if salary is <0 or not , if it is then do not set

```
public void setSalary (double yearSalary)
        {
            if(yearSalary >0 ){
                 ySalary = yearSalary;
           }
        }
```

Comment: This one still came back with -1.00

Comment: change if , if(yearSalary >0.0d )

Answer (score 0):

you are setting salary via and constructor, and setter is not used at all.
Add validation in constructor if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you please elaborate it. Please read [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)